# Stage velocity limit

Tags: navigation, simulation, simulator-stage, stageros, stage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having a serious issue with my Stage simulation.
No matter the velocity I send to my simulated robots, through /cmd_vel, Stage is always limiting the fields of twist to 1 (x, y, etc)!

I cannot find any references to this limitation or how/where to change it.
Does anyone know how to change this?
thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66124/stage-velocity-limit/) by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4402 on 2013-06-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Good question. I didn't remember seeing any options in the world files I've played with, just checked, and there weren't.

After a bit of digging in the ROS and Stage code, I found a reference to 'velocity_bounds', and 'acceleration_bounds' which can apparently be set by the world file:
http://rtv.github.io/Stage/group__model__position.html
My guess is that the default is 1m/s unless set otherwise.

Cheers,
Gavin

---

Originally posted by [Gav](https://answers.ros.org/users/3961/gav/) with karma: 478 on 2013-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2013-06-27**:
thanks a lot mate, it worked!